# "Group" childviews in ContainerView

Tags: ember.js

I am creating a dynamic dashboard and currently trying to achieve that with an ContainerView and childViews for the Widgets.
What I want to do now, is group, or rather wrap a div around a subset of childs. To give the proper example:
So lets say I create 4 childviews

```
App.IndexView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
    classNames: ['dashboard'],
    childViews: ['LinechartView', 'TableView', 'BarchartView', 'TabletwoView'],
    ...
```

So that works fine, as expected and it simply creates 4 divs around each. But what I want to do now, is put a div around the first two and the second two, so I can put them in the same "row" (using bootstrap).
Am I right in thinking that I would have to create a childview for each row, that is another containerview with each elements or columns being childviews of that? Or is there a simpler way?

To clarify, currently my DOM structure looks like this:

```
<div id="ember308" class="ember-view dashboard">
    <div id="ember311" class="ember-view">LinechartView</div>
    <div id="ember314" class="ember-view">TableView</div>
    <div id="ember317" class="ember-view">BarChartView</div>
    <div id="ember320" class="ember-view">TabletwoView</div>    
</div>
```

and I want my DOM Structure to be like this:

```
<div id="ember308" class="ember-view dashboard">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="ember311" class="ember-view span6">LinechartView</div>
        <div id="ember314" class="ember-view span6">TableView</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="ember317" class="ember-view span6">BarChartView</div>
        <div id="ember320" class="ember-view span6">TabletwoView</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is more about wrapping the row around the views rather than the additional span6 classes.
Any more help is really appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: i actually created a dashboard myself using EmberJS..having nested containerViews is the solution i suggest...coz that way u can add as many childViews possible dynamically..

Comment: I added an update to my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15624034/1164573

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Having nested `containerview` gets complex really quickly -- say you have a 3x2 grid and then the user resizes the window, and now you want to show 4 on the top row and 2 on the second row -- this is a pain to do if you use nested container views for rows.

If you want the contents of the dashboard to change dynamically based on what the user wants (i.e., some have 3 widgets, some have 15, can drag and drop to reorder), I think it makes the most sense to stick with one layer of `containerview`, and then use CSS to style them into grid. You can "simulate" a squary grid while your underlying DOM is actually a list of divs: here's an example: http://yaleclassroulette.com/. That uses the isotope library: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html.

**Original**:
While your solution (creating nested `containerviews`, the innerones for the rows) would work, I'm curious why you need the container view.

Have you considered ditching the container view, and doing the layout in a template instead? So change `App.IndexView` from `ContainerView` to a view backed by a template, which you can structure to your liking, and fill its child views using either `{{outlet}}` or `{{view}}`.

Example:

index_view.js:

```
 App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
   templateName: "index.hbs"
```

index.hbs:

```
 <div class="row1">
     {{view App.LinechartView stuffBinding="whatever.you.need.for.initialization"}}
     {{view App.TableView stuffBinding="whatever"}}
 </div>
 <div class="row2">
     {{view App.BarchartView stuffBinding="whatever"}}
     {{view App.TabletwoView stuffBinding="whatever"}}
 </div>
```

You can replace the views with outlets if you want more control over what is shown. In general, `ContainerView` is used if you want programmatic control over the views and care less about the structure -- do you in this case?

Comment: To be honest I am not a 100% sure if it is the best solution, and because of deadlines/presentations I have to show ui-progress quickly, but I want a completely dynamic dashboard. So Users could have 2 rows, but also 3 if they want, they could move the "widgets" around, possibly have 3 in a row, replace them, etc.
So the plan for later was, to create the childViews dynamically based on the User settings.
Also, and I don't really know right now if that's possible, I ideally wanted to just have e.g. one TableView but it could be created multiple times with different data. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Markus Check out my updated answer. I think in that case you would want to avoid nested containerviews, especially if you want to easily be able to reorder the dashboard items. Instead, try to keep the content (each dashboard item) in the same container view, but use CSS / JS to style it how you want. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for the answer Sherwin, I am not quite sure If I want to got down this route, since I don't really like the idea of being JS dependent for such simple lay-outing. But it would definitely a viable solution and I still have a lot to learn with emberjs, so I will probably see as I get more experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to have a secondary template wrapped around the primary template, you can use the layout property.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html, and then go to layout to check out the API.

Use layoutName property to have it backed by a template.

Comment: Ok, that looks in principle quite awesome and might even be a solution to my problem. Will check it out tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, the one thing that I thought I might have issues with. I can wrap each single ChildView in a div, but not 2 of them. I am still playing around with it, but please see my original post edits for what exactly I want

Comment: I don't think this will work because layouts can have at most one ```{{yield}}```, so the layout wouldn't let you selectively wrap two childviews in separate ```yields```.

Comment: Nested container views are going to get complicated, @sherwin-yu is right. Why do you need to put the row in there though? I thought all you needed was for the columns to equal 12 and it would figure that out for you?